# Nonblocking read sometimes drops data

Tags: c++, linux, named-pipes

I'm attempting to write interprocess communication for the following scenario:

- A "reader" (the program I am writing) listens continuously on a fifo.
- Writers appear and disappear in serial, like running `echo "[string]" > fifo_in` repeatedly.

---

Here is the reader logic I am using (as far as I know). The executable should be run from a directory containing `mkfifo the_fifo`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
                                    
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int fd = open("the_fifo", O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK);
    char buf[32];
    std::string line  = "";
    while(1) {
        ssize_t n_read = read(fd, buf, sizeof buf);
        if(n_read > 0) line.append(buf, n_read);
        std::cout << line;
        std::cout.flush();
        line = "";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This executable should print characters as they are written into `the_fifo`.

Occasionally when one runs `echo "[string]" > fifo_in` somewhere else on the system while this executable is running, the executable does not print the string.
What is going wrong?

Comment: The use of `fd_in` involves C-only APIs, so I doubt there's any difference between C and C++ (unless you use a third-party wrapper library). Also, the question you linked is arguably C++ as well (it makes use of `iostream` for output), despite being tagged C.

Comment: You need to provide a minimal self-contained example.

Comment: @ChristianChapman what about the code writing to fifo? Maybe it overflows?

Comment: @ChristianChapman not sure if you realize this, but since you are using `O_NONBLOCK` the read function will return immediately with `n_read == 0` even if there is no data to be read. In other words, it will spin endlessly and aimlessly.

Comment: The "code writing to the fifo" right now is just me executing this command in bash: `echo "some text, sometimes 32 chars sometimes more, sometimes less" > the_fifo;` It's fine that the reader's `read` call returns 0 most of the time since we don't know when an echo is going to come in. The reader should be spinning, waiting for it.

Comment: @ChristianChapman please add it to your question and which part of the echo does it "miss"?

Comment: @ChristianChapman OT, but you don't actually need `buf`: https://godbolt.org/z/7TsMvj9ar

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade No it won’t. It would return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` in that case.

Comment: But @OP why are you using non-blocking mode at all? If you're just going to spin there is no advantage, and smoking the CPU is a disadvantage.

Comment: @user207421 in the actual program the ‘while true’ has more things in it. This read operation is just one of the things the program attends to “as often as possible,” and we don’t want to block them. The actual program’s main loop also has blocks in it to avoid smoking

Comment: @user207421 if there is an active writer, you are correct. But, in this case there isn't. From [pipe(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) _"If any process has the pipe open for writing, reads fail with EAGAIN; otherwise—with no potential writers—reads succeed and return empty."_

Comment: @ChristianChapman I can't reproduce your problem with the example you've posted in your question

Comment: @Super-intelligentShade `read()` returning 0 in that case would indicate closure by the peer. This is rather different from 'no data available', which corresponds to `-1/errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`.

Comment: You should start writer and reader under monitoring of the program `strace`. There you can see what characters are *really* written and *really* read. This gives you a clear hint if characters are dropped while writing/by overflow/...

Comment: @user207421 run this snippet: https://godbolt.org/z/8oqrjY9cM and see for yourself. It will print an endless amount of `0`s and not `-1`s like you are saying. Again from pipe(7) man page: _"otherwise—with no potential writers—reads succeed and return empty."_ Which is what I've been trying to say.